# RxSwift limited Debounce to fire periodic events using additional time flag

Tags: swift, rx-swift, throttling, debouncing

I am in need of a debounce functionality in RxSwift which if certain time expires emits the even regardless of debounce condition.

e.g.
SETUP: debounce = 0.2 secs & periodic = 5 secs.

Case 1 (Needed) > If a user continuously pressing a button, i would like to receive an even if he doesn't stops continuous taps but only after a certain interval. This will give throttle like behaviour with periodic limit.

Case 2 (Works) > If user presses button every 0.5 sec, debounce limit won't be an issue and user will get his events every 0.5 secs.

Case 3 (Works) > User doesn't press anything, no event fired.

While debounce provides Case 2 & 3. Achieving case 1 is tricky.

---

Posting some clarification > My use case is not special panic button clicks. I know that throttle should be enough for it. Use case is more of a continuous stream of data. If data comes continuously in debounce limit (say 200ms), i want to have a throttle behaviour giving response say every 2 seconds but if data is not coming very frequently say every 0.5 secs, i want data to be sent immediately by observable for UI to be more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you are describing the `throttle` operator, not the `denounce` operator.

In general, you should use throttle when dealing with button clicks/triggers and denounce when dealing with data input.

Comment: I am dealing with data input. My issue with debounce is that unless data input stops, it doesn't trigger any event because events are coming every 50ms to 20secs. If even flow is fast, i need throttle, if its slow, i want debounce.

Comment: Try using throttle anyway and be sure to try with `latest:` set to both true and false to see which gives you what you want.

Comment: At present i am using throttle & it does work fine :)